# How to generate a summary of a linear model using two conditions in R?

Tags: r, linearmodels

Assume that a dataset has the variables Age, Gender and Height. How to create a linear model based on age that only considers ages between 18 to 21.

This is what i have so far and it works, but I don't know how the && operator works in R.

```
model1 <- lm(formula = Age > 18 ~ Gender + Height, data = myDataSet)
```

But when I try adding my second condition the following error occurs:

```
model2 <- lm(formula = Age > 18 && <21 ~ Gender + Height, data = myDataSet)
```

**ERROR:**

```
 Error: unexpected '<' in:
"model2 <- lm(
  data=myDataSet, formula= Age > 18 && <"
```

---

**user11916948 ANSWER:**

```
model3 <- lm(formula = Age>18 & Age<21 ~ Gender + Height, data = myDataSet)
summary(model3)
```

Comment: What is `>21` ? What is it supposed to be greater than?

Comment: Should be Age. I just tried `lm(formula = Age > 18 && Age < 21 ~ Gender + Height, data = myDataSet)` which also didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
age>18 & age<21
```

Comment: pffffff. hahah * flips the desk *. thanks , really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to create two different models for the Age being in two ranges, then you have to use corresponding datasets:

```
model1 <- lm(formula = Age ~ Gender + Height, data = myDataSet[which(myDataSet$Age < 18), ])

model2 <- lm(formula = Age ~ Gender + Height, data = myDataSet[which(myDataSet$Age > 18 & myDataSet$Age < 21), ])
```

The above models will predict Age (numerical value). The models which are described in the question will predict whether the age < 18 or not (TRUE / FALSE value)